# Как удалить свой аккаунт

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника

Удалите мой аккаунт с вашего форума. (Сам не нашел где это сделать).

Абсолютно неудобный, бесполезный. Где много спрашивать нельзя, в диалоге участвовать нельзя, ничего нельзя. Какие-то люди исправляют твои сообщения, удаляют комментарии. Ответ нужно ждать сутками, да и то, в нем нет ответа на вопрос. В ответе пишут какой ты тупой, что ты задал много вопросов, что ты не показал решение (где мне его взять, если я за решением к вам и пришёл).

Это самый убогий и ничтожный, неудобный и неприятный форум.

Comment: возможно Вы просто ошиблись... это не форум. удачи вам

Comment: по хозяйски так.

Comment: Хочешь быстро и хорошо - обращайся за деньги на специальные сайты.

Comment: Мужик красава! :-) Плюсанул нипадеццки! :-)

Comment: Это не форум, а Q&А сайт. Четкий вопрос — четкий. Плохой вопрос (не по теме, неясный и т.д) будут закрывать, минусовать, и удалять.  Оскорблять сообщество было необязательно .

Comment: Исправляют ваши сообщения, чтобы они соответствовали правилам, были яснее, правят орфографию и т.д. Решать за вас не будут.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 нипадеццки это если плюсанул и сразу +10

Answer (score 3):

Полностью солидарен.Заходите в свой профиль, там есть вкладка править и внизу будет удаление.